# How do i dynamically name Linklabels?

Tags: c#, winforms

Im trying to dynamically change the name of the linklabel to be able to cycle them throught the for statment, but due to my lack of programming knowledge im not able to accomplish it.

If u could explain every step i wold really appreciate it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 205; i++)
{
    if (LinkLabel# + i.Text == "name")
    {
        // do stuff

    }
}
```

Comment: Store them in an array and reference them by index (e.g. `LinkLabel[] yourLabels`, then later use `yourLabels[i]`).

Comment: i got 205 labels, isnt there a simpler way ?

Comment: How are you creating the labels? If you're literally dropping them all into the designer, you're making your life hard right from the start. If you're creating them dynamically in code, then no - storing them in an array (or really any structure of your choosing) is not only safer than finding them by name (in case something changes) but should be super trivial to set up as well.

Comment: hmm... didnt see that aprouch to creating the labels, but dont i need to do this code by myself every single one of them ?
`code`
            this.linkLabel76.AutoSize = true;
            this.linkLabel76.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(435, 537);
            this.linkLabel76.Name = "linkLabel76";
            this.linkLabel76.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(61, 13);
            this.linkLabel76.TabIndex = 141;
            this.linkLabel76.TabStop = true;
            this.linkLabel76.Text = "linkLabel76";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search the controls on the form by name to get a reference to them.

`LinkLabel ll = (LinkLabel)this.Controls["LinkLabel" + i];`

This can throw exceptions though if the casting fails, or the control is not found.

A safer way would be to use pattern matching:

```
if (this.Controls["LinkLabel" + i] is LinkLabel ll)
{
    // do stuff with ll
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (suggested by @Broots Waymb) would be to dynamically create the link label controls and add them to the form. Here is some sample code that I adapted this from some other code that I am already using. (not tested, but looks like it should work)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// List for storing references to the LinkLabels
    /// </summary>
    List<LinkLabel> m_LinkLabels = new List<LinkLabel>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates and places all the LinkLabels on the form
    /// </summary>
    private void CreateLinkLabels()
    {
        int startingX = 100;        // starting top left X coordinate for first link label
        int startingY = 100;        // starting top left Y coordinate for first link label
        int xOffset = 20;           // horizontal space between labels
        int yOffset = 20;           // vertical space between labels
        int labelsToCreate = 100;   // total number of labels to create
        int labelsPerRow = 10;      // number of labels in each row
        int labelWidth = 61;        // width of the labels
        int labelHeight = 13;       // height of the labels

        int labelsInCurrentRow = 0; // number of labels in the current row
        int x = startingY;          // current x coordinate
        int y = startingX;          // current y coordinate
        int tabIndexBase = 65;      // base number for tab indexing 

        for (int i = 0; i < labelsToCreate; i++)
        {
            // update coordinates for next row
            if (labelsInCurrentRow == labelsPerRow)
            {
                x = startingX;
                y += yOffset;
                labelsInCurrentRow = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                x += xOffset;
                labelsInCurrentRow++;
            }

            // create the label
            LinkLabel ll = new LinkLabel()
            {
                Name = "LinkLabel" + (i + 1), // +1 to correct zero based index
                AutoSize = true,
                Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y),
                Size = new System.Drawing.Size(labelWidth, labelHeight),
                TabIndex = tabIndexBase + i,
                TabStop = true,
                Text = "LinkLabel" + (i + 1) // +1 to correct zero based index
            };

            // add the label to the list
            m_LinkLabels.Add(ll);
        }

        // add all controls in the list to the form
        this.Controls.AddRange(m_LinkLabels.ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: this is a great idea but isnt heavier on the cpu than creating thought the designer ?

Comment: Not really. The designer does most of this work anyway, it is just spelled out the long way in the .designer.cs file. The only extra bit is the math on the coordinates which is pretty negligible.